# Life or lives in this context

Tags: grammatical-number

I have this sentence:
The best engineers optimize every aspect of their lives.

Should it be "lives" or "life"?

I'm thinking lives because engineers is plural.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "The best engineers optimize all aspects of their lives."  It's the singular "aspect" that is confusing you in your version of the sentence.